# modeling extra table information with django's contenttypes

Tags: django, content-type

I've just started using Django's contenttypes framework (and it's pretty awesome). I have an Area object that has many specialised Block objects - I've modeled it as below.

```
class Area(models.Model):
    ...

class SomeBlock(models.Model):
    ...

class AreaBlock(models.Model):
    area = models.ForeignKey(Area)
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    block_object = generic.GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')
```

This works very well. Now I want to register these specialised blocks in their own table along with extra 'global' information about it.

```
class BlockRegistrar(models.Model):
    ...
```

My problem is joining SomeBlock to it's global information in the BlockRegistrar model. A foreignkey in the block table would be obvious, but it wouldn't ever change and I can't figure out how to use django's ContentType table to do these joins.

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

So `AreaBlock.block_object` is a GenericForeignKey to one of several possible `SomeXXBlock` models?

Do you mean every `SomeXXBlock` record has a corresponding `BlockRegistrar` record?

The easiest way to do that would be with [model inheritance](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/db/models/#model-inheritance):

```
class BlockRegistrar(models.Model):
    # 'global' fields common to all SomeXXBlock models
    ...

class SomeBlock(BlockRegistrar):
    ...

class SomeOtherBlock(BlockRegistrar):
    ...
```

Behind the scenes Django automatically creates a OneToOneField linking the `SomeXXBlock` instance to it's corresponding `BlockRegistrar`. In Django this is called 'multi-table inheritance'. From your question it sounds like this may be what you want.

If you never need to access a `BlockRegistrar` object directly, but just want the global fields to be available on all the `SomeXXBlock` 'child' models then you could use an Abstract base model:

```
class BlockRegistrar(models.Model):
    # 'global' fields common to all SomeXXBlock models
    ...
    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class SomeBlock(BlockRegistrar):
    ...

class SomeOtherBlock(BlockRegistrar):
    ...
```

In this case the `BlockRegistrar` model does not exist as a table in the db and there is no magic OneToOneField added to the `SomeXXBlock` models.